# Как запретить событие родителя дочернему элементу?

Tags: javascript, события, draggable

```js
let offsetX;
let offsetY;
let parent = document.getElementById("parent");

function moveParent() {
  parent.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
    offsetX = event.offsetX;
    offsetY = event.offsetY;
  })

  parent.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {
    parent.style.top = (event.pageY - offsetY) + "px";
    parent.style.left = (event.pageX - offsetX) + "px";
  })
}
moveParent();
```

```css
#parent {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#son {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" draggable="true">
  <div id="son"></div>
</div>
```

Как видно в коде есть Parent и внутри него элемент Son. Нужно сделать так, чтобы "хватая" за элемент Son Parent не передвигался, а передвигался только при хватании только его самого то есть то что серое(нажмите "Выполнить код").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добавьте в начало обработчиков событий
if(e.target!＝parent)
    return;

Comment: Где именно это добавить?

Comment: А вы пробовали свой вариант?) Что-то e.target всегда указывает на parent.

Comment: действительно не работает, я не проверял, а на глаз прикинул и не получилось :)
Вот работающий код: https://codepen.io/HTMLProgrammer/pen/qBbdBRP